# How to trigger a span click event on an icon wrapped in a span?

Tags: reactjs, events, onclick

I have a basic react ToggleBtn component that changes the up/down icon and triggers a modal.  The button consists of text and an icon wrapped in a span.  The problem is the event.target is different when clicking the icon.  When the text on the span is clicked, it triggers a span click event, which bubbles up to the button handler.  However, if you click the icon, it triggers an svg click event.  This is a problem because the location of the modal is tied to the object being clicked.  So the modal is positioned incorrectly if the icon is clicked.
Note: I am wrapping the text and icon in a span so they display side by side.  Is there a way to make the icon trigger the spans click event and not an svg click event?  Please see code below:

```
const ToggleBtn = ({ btnName, children, showContent, handleBtnClick }) => {

  const [displayProjectToggle, setDisplayProjectToggle] = useState(false);

  const handleShow = (event, btnName) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Content: Event:", event.target);
    console.log("Content: Event:", btnName)
    console.log("Content: Event:", event.target.parentElement);

    handleBtnClick(event, btnName);
    // console.log("BtnName:", btnnName);
    setDisplayProjectToggle(!displayProjectToggle);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log("displayProjectToggle:", displayProjectToggle)
  }, [displayProjectToggle]);

  return (
    <div className={showContent ? "content-toggle-show" : "content-toggle-hide"}>
      <div className="content-toggle-chevron">
        <button
          className="nav-link dropdown-btn"
          d
          onClick={(e) => handleShow(e, btnName)}
        >
          <span
            className="flex-container1"
            data-dropdown="dropdown2" aria-expanded="false"
            name="discover"
          >
            {btnName + " "}
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              className="mg-l-4 content-dropdown-header"
              data-dropdown="dropdown2" aria-expanded="false" name="discover"
              icon={
                displayProjectToggle
                  ? "fa-solid fa-chevron-down"
                  : "fa-solid fa-chevron-up"
              }
            />
          </span>

        </button>

      </div>{" "}
      {/*Header*/}

      {/*Content*/}
      <div className={displayProjectToggle ? "content-toggle-show" : "content-toggle-hide"}>{children}</div>
      {/*Content*/}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ToggleBtn;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue you're facing with the icon triggering an SVG click event is because SVG elements, including the  component, have their own event handling that can be different from regular HTML elements. To make the icon trigger the span's click event, you can use a combination of CSS and a label element to wrap both the text and the icon and style it to look like a button.

Here's an updated version of your ToggleBtn component that achieves this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

const ToggleBtn = ({ btnName, children, showContent, handleBtnClick }) => {
const [displayProjectToggle, setDisplayProjectToggle] = useState(false);

const handleShow = (event, btnName) => {
 event.preventDefault();
 event.stopPropagation();
 handleBtnClick(event, btnName);
 setDisplayProjectToggle(!displayProjectToggle);
};

  useEffect(() => {
   // console.log("displayProjectToggle:", displayProjectToggle)
  }, [displayProjectToggle]);

 return (
   <div className={showContent ? 'content-toggle-show' : 'content-toggle- 
  hide'}>
  <div className="content-toggle-chevron">
    <label
      className="nav-link dropdown-btn"
      onClick={(e) => handleShow(e, btnName)}
    >
      <span className="flex-container1" data-dropdown="dropdown2" aria- 
    expanded="false" name="discover">
        {btnName + ' '}
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          className="mg-l-4 content-dropdown-header"
          data-dropdown="dropdown2"
          aria-expanded="false"
          name="discover"
          icon={
            displayProjectToggle
              ? 'fa-solid fa-chevron-down'
              : 'fa-solid fa-chevron-up'
          }
        />
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>

  {/* Content */}
  <div className={displayProjectToggle ? 'content-toggle-show' : 'content- 
  toggle-hide'}>{children}</div>
  {/* Content */}
   </div>
  );
  };

export default ToggleBtn;
```

In this updated code, I've wrapped the text and icon in a label element instead of a button, and I've applied the necessary CSS styles to make it look like a button. This should ensure that clicking both the text and the icon triggers the handleShow function and not separate SVG click events.

Comment: Thank for the info, based on the knowleget that SVG elements have their own click events, I was able to resolve this issue by adding a class "icon-container" to the FontAwesomeIcon element.  The icon-container rule sets pointer-events to none for the icon.

pointer-events: none;